SwiftUI - Comparison of a Binding variable in onTapGesture (to toggle selection of a row in a Grid)
I'm able to get a row item selected using onTapGesture, and deselected if it is tapped again.
The question is why does the following code work, but the code shown at the end did not?
@Binding var selectedRow: RowItem?

var body: some View {

    ForEach(modelData.rows) { row in

        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            Text("text")
            Text("text")
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            if (selectedRow?.id == row.id) {
                selectedRow = nil
            } else {
                selectedRow = row
            }
        }
    }
}

where modelData.rows is [RowItem],
and RowItem is: struct RowItem: Identifiable
and has an equality function defined:
static func == (lhs: RowItem, rhs: RowItem) -> Bool {
        rhs.id == lhs.id
    }

Why must the id be used, and the following didn't work?
.onTapGesture {
    if (selectedRow? == row) {
        selectedRow = nil
    } else {
        selectedRow = row
    }
}

(Fails with:)

The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions


Remove the equality function, you are literally telling SwiftUI to only refresh if the id changes. That custom Equatable will cause systemic issues.

The error "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time" is something you often see when a parenthesis is missing, or there is a typo, or you are trying to access a property that doesn't exist, or there is some other trivial error that most compilers would be able to spot without difficulty. But not Xcode.
When I tried your failing case with Xcode 16.1, the error was actually a bit more helpful:

Value of optional type 'RowItem?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'RowItem'

This confusion is because the equality function is unnecessary. So you can begin by deleting the equality function. The error then changes to:

Operator function '==' requires that 'ContentView.RowItem' conform to 'Equatable'

This problem is fixed by specifically declaring that RowItem conforms to Equatable:
struct RowItem: Identifiable, Equatable { ...

The error then changes to:

'?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript

So the final fix is to remove the ?. In Swift, you are allowed to compare an optional with a non-optional, the optional is automatically unwrapped if in fact it is not nil. Btw, you don't need to surround the expression with parentheses in Swift either:
.onTapGesture {
    if selectedRow == row {
        selectedRow = nil
    } else {
        selectedRow = row
    }
}


Thanks!  Explicitly indicating conformance to Equatable (along with the other change) was indeed the solution.  (While removing the == function may have helped to find the problem, it was of course necessary to keep it for conformance to Equatable.)
